# keras using euclidean distance loss function

Tags: python, keras

I have some problem with Keras custom loss function.
When I run my Keras model using this loss function, then my loss value is `NaN`.

```py
def euc_dist_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis = -1, keepdims = True)))
```

this is my code.

```
(X_train,Y_train),(X_test,Y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train4D = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],28,28,1).astype("float32")
X_test4D = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],28,28,1).astype("float32")

X_train4D_normalize = X_train4D/255
X_test4D_normalize = X_test4D/255

Y_trainOneHot = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train)
Y_testOneHot = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='same',input_shape=(28,28,1),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=36,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='same',input_shape=(14,14,1),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#output layer
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())


model.compile(loss=euc_dist_keras,optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
train_history = model.fit(x=X_train4D_normalize,y=Y_trainOneHot,validation_split=0.2\
                          ,epochs=10,batch_size=1,verbose=1)
```

Comment: Try reducing batch size to 1. If it starts to return finite values than the problem is due to you get a very large number when you compute loss. To solve this normalize your data to be in range `(0, 1)`. Otherwise, problem is with the values you pass `y_pred` or `y_true`.

Comment: The loss value return inf when I reduce my batch size to 1.But my input data y_pred and y_true are already in range (0,1)

Comment: What are the values of `y_true` and `y_pred` that you pass?

Comment: I pass gray level value of image and then the value divided by 255.

Comment: Before you pass it divide it by 255.

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: You're not doing it, if you do it your code would work. Check your code.

Comment: I already add my code on the upside.I sure that I am doing it.